# Using the value of an option in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

Is there a way to get and use the value of an option (not env variable) passed to a Makefile? E.g. if the -j option (for parallelism) is passed on the command line, how do I access it inside the Makefile?

Answer (score 1):

In GNU Make, most options are detectable by inspecting the value of `MAKEFLAGS` (using `findstring`). That value is a string of "canonical" one-letter variants of options, usually.  For example if you run Make as `make --keep-going --question`, `MAKEFLAGS` will be `"kq"`.

`-j` is different, though.  If you run `make -j`, `MAKEFLAGS` will contain `-j`.  If you run `make -j2`, `MAKEFLAGS` will contain `-j --jobserver-ids,3,4`.

So you have enough information to distinguish the cases "not parallel at all", "parallel and unlimited" and "parallel and limited".  No way to know what the `<num>` in the last case is, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the parameter of `-j` you can use the `.MAKE.JOBS`. Generally the `MAKEFLAGS` variable is your desired variable.

Maybe there aren't available in every `make` (they are available in FreeBSD's `make`).

Comment: Looks like .MAKE.JOBS is not available in GNU make.

Answer (score 1):

As Michael Livshin says, you can't know... unless you upgrade to GNU make 4.2 or higher; from the [NEWS](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS?h=4.2) file:

```
* The amount of parallelism can be determined by querying MAKEFLAGS, even when
  the job server is enabled (previously MAKEFLAGS would always contain only
  "-j", with no number, when job server was enabled).
```

Which basically means that the `-j2` will appear in `MAKEFLAGS` always, not just `-j` as before.

Be aware that changing this value won't have any effect, though, if that's what you're interested in... the amount of parallelism is set when the first make command is invoked and all other make commands will use that same value.  All you can do is disable parallelism completely, you can't change the amount of it.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't looking at changing it but passing it on to a compiler which supports a similar option (gox for Go).

Comment: Just be aware you're "double-dipping" on CPU then, because make will be using N jobs to start N different gox operations, and each gox operation will be building with N different threads... so I guess more like "square-dipping" :).